# Real-time user notifications from backend with PubNub, scalability, and over 9000 chat rooms

Tags: javascript, node.js, websocket, pubnub

I'm working on a pretty fun web app project that can become rather big, and I have a chance to play around with this handy thing called `PubNub` as main real-time engine of application.

So it's a web application with `Node.js` backend, involves potentially huge amount of chat rooms between users and realtime notifications sent to users by backend when some data in DB is updated.

Usually, developing with `Sockets.io`, I will just subscribe each user to channel of his unique DB id, and also to chanels representing different chat rooms.

This way I can handle chat rooms and authentication on backend and after storing some personal notification in DB I can easily push them to channel named by user id, so if user is online - he gets it, if not - fine, he will see it on next login, notification is already in DB. And theoretically this monstrocity should scale just fine horizontally with help of redis pub/sub.

Thing that worries me about PubNub in this case is scalability. As I obviously have no insight on what is going on in PubNub backend's dark corners, I want to make sure that app is built in the way that it will be prepared to handle some obscure enormously huge amount of simultaneous users.

My question is, what is the best approach to building such a system with `PubNub`?

1. Am I correct assuming that it will be better, in need of pushing notification to specific user, to subscribe to this user's pubnub, push note and unsubscribe. As if I will keep all online-user channels open - then there is no point in PubNub instead of websockets on my server, as server will be anyway under load of all of those opened online-user channels and should be scaled just to maintain huge quantity of them.
2. What about user authorisation? Without involving my backend how can I be sure that user posting some message will not be able to fake his personality and will have exatly the same as he have authenticated inside application?
3. And generally (and via PubNub) what is the best practice to tackle huge amounts of chats per users? As say during application life each user may accumulate some decent amount of garbage chat rooms that have some users in it, though havn't been touched by anyone for a long time, and users just way too lazy to leave it manually?

Thanks for Your patience in reading this wall of text!

Comment: The question is actually quite nice, but really too long and is asking to many questions, I believe.

If you just want to have a hint: yes, `PubNub` will probably withstand your requirements, since we have felt it to be very well engineered. 

I hope you have read up already, that `PubNub` uses Socket.IO (or dependencies) under the hood, but does the heavy lifting - scaling - for you.

Comment: Yes I was aware that it may be too big for stack overflow, but I had no place to ask it except SO as pubnub site states that community forums are now here.
I'm trying to wrap my head aroung it today, and stuck with one thought... how can i implement unread messages without involving backend that will listen to all chat rooms? I need to listen to rooms to track timestamps and then get ALL of the user chat rooms (that potentially unlimited) and compare this user timestamps with lastmessage timestamps? Sounds completely ineffective. Any quick thoughts on that matter?

Comment: Maybe I need just to slice this question to few smaller ones to make it easier for SO to digest.
Also removed a chat history question, figured out that it can be handled fine by pubnub storage.

Comment: @eljefedelrodeodeljefe oops forgot to tag you in previous comments, thanks for reply by the way!

Comment: you can always send to support@pubnub.com, too. But I will answer at a high level here soon.

Comment: @CraigConover I was aiming for doing so, but wanted to give a shot for a wider community first. Thanks, will wait for your answer!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

**UPDATED Dec 5, 2021**
If you are implementing a chat app, please refer to the [PubNub Chat use-case documentation](https://www.pubnub.com/docs/chat/overview) for full details. It has new features and UI components that are built upon [the PubNub Platform](https://www.pubnub.com/docs/).

**UPDATED May 15, 2020**
We have [some new docs](http://www.pubnub.com/docs/platform/channels/overview) that will explain much of the below in much clearer terms.

And new features that can be applied to many of the questions/answers below:

- [Message Actions](http://www.pubnub.com/docs/platform/channels/annotate)
- [Message Counts](http://www.pubnub.com/docs/platform/channels/retrieve#getting-message-counts)
- [Batch History (multi-channel message fetch)](http://www.pubnub.com/docs/platform/channels/retrieve#retrieving-messages)
- [Objects (Users, Channels and Memberships Metadata)](https://www.pubnub.com/docs/web-javascript/pubnub-objects)

**NOTE:** I've sprinkled some of the above links down in the answers below.

---

First, let's address this...

> Thing that worries me about PubNub, in this case, is scalability. As I
> obviously have no insight on what is going on in PubNub backend's dark
> corners, I want to make sure that the app is built in a way that it will
> be prepared to handle some obscure enormously huge amount of
> simultaneous users.

and this...

> then there is no point in PubNub instead of WebSockets on my server,
> as the server will be anyway under the load of all of those opened online-user
> channels and should be scaled just to maintain the huge quantity of them

This is sort of backward because you would use a service like PubNub to ensure that your application scales to handle millions of users. PubNub has thousands of customers that scale to millions of users and 100's of billions of messages. Not knowing how PubNub does this frees you to implement the biz logic of your application.

But I think I get what you are saying. You are under the impression that your server has to be involved in each and every chat room interaction for every user, but that is only partially true. Mostly, your server will be used for authentication, some subscription maintenance (optional), and probably for sending messages out to one, many, or all end users, as required (depends on your requirements).

Here are some attempts to answer your questions although they are kind of a bit all over the place so I will do my best to answer what I think it is you are asking.

### Question 1

*This question seems to be directed at maintaining lots of subscriptions to channels and the scalability of that.*

Generally speaking, every end-user initializes PubNub and subscribes to channels they need to listen to and publish to channels they need to send messages on. Typically, the channels (chat rooms in your case, I assume) they are publishing on are the same channels they are subscribing to, but they are different kinds of use cases. And you can subscribe to thousands of channels at a time (up to 20K per client). If you did this with WebSockets, how would you go about scaling this to millions of users? You would implement and operate (to scale) something similar to PubNub (not easy and not cheap).

Now, if a user is subscribed to a bunch of chat room channels but some or many are stale (user hasn't viewed or posted to in a while), you could have some code on your server (or the client) that monitors the activity of users and unsubscribes them from those stale channels. This is possible using [channels groups](https://www.pubnub.com/knowledge-base/categories/channel-groups). Each end-user would have their own channel group that contains all the channels they are listening to. And the client code or the server code and add and remove channels to/from those end users' channel groups.

### Question 2

**UPDATED DOCS**: https://www.pubnub.com/docs/platform/security/access-control

*Now this question is a bit more clear and focused and is asking about authentication (login) and how to ensure someone is who they say they are and how to handle authorization (what they can and cannot do) and where/who controls this.*

The answer is, you control the authentication (login) to prove that the person is what they say they are. Your log-in process checks for a valid username/password and in the user record, you will have a list of access controls for that user. With that, you generate an auth-key that you grant read and/or write access to one or more channels. This grant is a PubNub operation that your server invokes. The auth-key is passed back to the client and the client code initializes PubNub instance using the pub/sub keys and this auth-key that PubNub servers use to check for access based on the channel and the operation being requested (subscribe to this channel, publish to that channel, etc). If the auth-key does not have the proper access, the PubNub server will deny access (403 response).

There's more to all of this but this is a good start. Read up on PubNub Access Manager for the SDK you will be using on our docs page. For example, you can start with the [JavaScript SDK Access Manager docs and tutorials](https://www.pubnub.com/docs/web-javascript/pam-security).

### Question 3

**UPDATED DOCS**: https://www.pubnub.com/docs/platform/channels/receive#subscribe-to-channels

I believe I answered this sufficiently with question 1 - Channel Groups. Start with the [JavaScript SDK Stream Controller (which provides Channel Group feature) docs and tutorials](https://www.pubnub.com/docs/web-javascript/stream-controller).

I hope I have managed to move you a few steps further along your journey to a highly successful real-time, data stream application using PubNub. Please reply with any additional questions you may still have.

---

*Answers to your new comments:*

Thanks for your follow-up comments. It is very clear what you are asking now.

> I will need to compare chat room timestamp with personal user last-read timestamp for this, so it seems that I need to listen to those channels from back-end and update user's last-reads, or to trust into the front-end, and get timestamps from a user directly

No, you do not have to listen to the channels on your server. Yes, from the client app, you will keep the timestamp of the last received message. When the user comes back online, you use this timestamp to get history for the channels the client was subscribed to. Many have done this successfully and we are going to be releasing some amazing features in the coming months that will simplify this considerably.

> pushing real-time notifications to users from the back-end. Do I need to be subscribed to all of my user channels if I want to push notes to them at any time?

You can publish on any channel without actually subscribing to it first. So your server can publish to channels as it needs to.

And as before, keep coming with more questions as you require.

---

*Great follow-up questions again. Here's what I suggest*

> ... it makes sense to not request all of those chat rooms from DB and join via pubnub all of them, but rather implement pagination... how user can be aware of new messages that may appear in his old chat rooms?

Again, you can stay subscribed to 20K channels using channel groups. You can subscribe to 10 channel groups with 2K channels per channel group - but I'd recommend just limiting the user to 100 or less because that seems like a sufficient limit to impose in your app. But pick whatever upper limit you want and when the user hits that limit, force them to leave another chat room first or suggest they leave one of the top 10 most inactive, or some algorithm that makes sense for your app.

**UPDATED DOCS**: https://www.pubnub.com/docs/platform/channels/receive#subscribe-to-channels

Getting the # of missed messages does require a full history fetch, but we are going to be providing improved APIs to make this simpler in the near future. But if the user is registered for push notifications on all these channels, the device would be able to receive these push messages and your app can keep that count locally. We will have a "how to update the badge count in background" article being published soon. You could also use that to keep track of the number of missed messages per channel (chat room).

> For now I just want to limit the number of rooms available for users to let's say a hundred and request and join them without pagination.

**UPDATED DOCS**: https://www.pubnub.com/docs/platform/channels/retrieve

We do have customers that do this without worrying about pagination. They just retrieve history on the 100 channels the device is subscribed to. With the background badge count updater strategy, you will have the advantage to know which channels to fetch from when the app becomes active. I will post the link to that article here once it is published.

Comment: And if you google PubNub + [specific questions], you will likely find some answers on our website, StackOverflow or other sites. The more specific the question the better. But we'll help steer you along to the right answers.

Comment: Thanks for such a good high level explanation, though my impression of need for backend involvement is based not on a simple misunderstanding of a whole concept but rather of trying to wrap my head around some specific implementation strategies, again as i mentioned before how can i implement detection of messages that wasnt read by user. i will need to compare chat room timestamp with personal user last-read timestamp for this, so it seems that i need to listen to those channels from back-end and update user's last-reads, or to trust in to front end, and get timestamps from a user directly.

Comment: Or am i missing something and there is a way to go around it using purely (or at least mostly) client side PubNub?

Comment: Oh and first question was about pushing realtime notifications to users from back-end. Do i need to be subscribed to all of my user channels if i want to push notes to them at any time (as i suppose all of those separate channels will be a separate TCP connection) or I can send notes without subsctibing to them (i.e open TCP channel, send, close TCP channel).
And google is always my first resort though i was unable to find answer to unread messages implementation question.

Comment: Nor good explanations of use cases when you need to send realtime data to all of your clients from backend.

Comment: Oh ok, this last answers really clarified some things for me! 
One more question, one thing bothers me. Let's imagine edge case when a user have a few thousands of chat rooms. So for efficiency sake it makes sence to not request all of those chat rooms from DB and join via pubnub all of them, but rather implement pagination that will get only top 20 and then others as users scrolls chat room's list. But if i will join only this top 20 from a first page, how user can be aware of a new messages that may appear in his old chat rooms?

Comment: For now i just want to limit amount of rooms available for users to let's say a hundred and request and join them without pagination. But maybe you have some quick thoughts of more elegant high-level solution?
Again with websockets it's possible to make some kind of signalling that will  rejoin user from back-end to old room on new messages, but i think that i'm missing some simple and elegant solution for that...

Comment: btw, answer accepted as I think that my initial question was answered fully. Thank you for a great support!

Comment: Background badge count updater technic sound interesting, will wait for the link. Now i have more or less complete picture of the system that i need to implement to have PubNub integrated elegantly. Thanks for your time, Craig!

Comment: Max - here is the badge count background solution I mentioned. https://github.com/pubnub/badgeCountDemo  It is still rough and will be purified for a blog soon but should provide a good insight on how to keep track of which channels need to have history fetched. It is a slightly different use case of this repo. If you have questions, hit us up directly at support@pubnub.com

Comment: Thanks, Craig, will take a look.

Comment: Many things have changed over the years and there are plenty of new features that fulfill the challenges that Max experienced. I have updated my answer with a link to our Chat docs which includes React, Swift, Android (and platforms to come) open source Chat UI Components and sample apps.